# Regarding multiple springboot services instances accessibility on docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Have a Springboot application which has rest controllers and all rest APIs have been defined like below

```
http://localhost:**8080**/myapplication/restcall/user/{userID}
```

This application has been deployed on docker and running an instance on docker where docker host port 8080 has been mapped with container port 8080 and I am able to run this application successfully.

Now the issue is when i create multiple instances of web application which can be accessed on different ports like http://localhost:8181/myapplication etc but all my internal rest controllers can not be invoked because all rest calls from client is going on 8080 and hence they are not working.

Am i missing something because how scaling can be done for a web application in this use-case.

Comment: Docker can map internal ports to different external ports. Maybe you should do that

Comment: That is done and i am able to map 8181,8080 and anyports with internal port 8080 and i a able to access appliation. But issue is happening when rest services are hit  because from outside browser when a rest service always try to hit 8080.

so if application is being accessed at http://localhost:32687, my browser is rejecting a rest service request at localhost:8080.It says 403 forbidden.

Comment: you probably need to use nginx or something like this for this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so after all i got my issue resolved, i was doing mistake when i was declaring my rest service. I removed the part till port number from the rest URI declarations and it worked.

/myapplication/restcall/user/{userID}

Now i can scale my web application any number of instances and all are working fine.
Thanks